# validation messages don't display all at the same time with custom validation on MVC3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, customvalidator, custom-validators

I have made some custom validations looking like this

```
if (UnEquip == false && (Salaries < 1 || Salaries > 1000000))
{
    yield return new ValidationResult("Le champ 'Nombre de salariés' doit être renseigné et compris entre 1 et 1000000", new[] { "Salaries" });
}
```

The validation works just fine, but if i have an error on a validator that is not custom, the error messages from the custom validators doesn't show. They areas displayed only if there is only error from a custom validation.
i've tried turning off client side validation, but without any success.

i'm using a validationSummary,Jquery.validate and Jquery.Unobstrusive as scripts.

I have no clue on how to display every error messages at the same time, it seems it's a problème in the js.

Comment: Use `if(ModelState.IsValid)` on controller to validate fields.

Answer (score 0):

Use `if(ModelState.IsValid)` on controller to validate fields.

Comment: the validation itself works just fine, only the error messages have a problem. the custom validator messages only show themselves if there is no other validation messages to display

Answer (score 0):

Did you implement the "IClientValidatable" interface?

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/275056/Custom-Client-Side-Validation-in-ASP-NET-MVC3

Comment: i was using IValidatableObject interface, i'll try this

Comment: and you must use if(ModelState.IsValid) too as others already answered

Comment: yes i know, the validation works. the only problem i have is with the messages not displaying if i have other validation messages to display.